# Restore the priceless comment please

Tags: support, status-declined, deleted-comments, historical-lock

Bellow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273868/476681), there was a comment, which was even better then the answer.

[This page](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Perl_vs_Java) shows the original comment as :

```
Go -f>@+?*<.-&'_:$#/%! yourself! – Schwern
```

It may sound insulting, but in this context is actually very funny.

Can one of the moderators restore the comment?

Comment: It is a shame people feel the need to flag perfectly harmless comments like that though -.-

Comment: @OGHaza "f*** you" is a very bad insult, but the comment is written in such a way that it is even funnier then the answer itself (read the rest of the comments bellow the answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. That question is permanently frozen and even if we could make any changes to it, since that comment is archived on the page you link to anyway, I don't see why we should bother. We have more important things to do.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware the process is so complex. I thought it is only checking/unchecking a box, or something similar.